# Canada visa refused because I had to cancel my trip and did not submit passport in time

Tags: canada, visa-refusals

I applied for a visa to Canada and was already instructed to submit my passport (I guess pretty much should be accepted after that), however, I had a medical emergency and had to cancel my trip. I forgot about the application altogether so I did not withdraw my application, and today the status was refused because I did not submit my passport.

I was wondering if this affect any visa application in the future and should I put 'Yes' to any question regarding history of visa refusals from now on?

The letter reads:

> Thank you for your interest in visiting Canada. After careful review
>   of your temporary resident visa application and supporting
>   documentation, I have determined that your application does not meet
>   the requirements of the Immigration and Refugee Protection Act (IRPA)
>   and Immigration and Refugee Protection Regulations (IRPR). I am
>   refusing your application on the following grounds: You have not
>   complied with our request for information, per subsection 16(1) of the
>   IRPA. To date, you have failed to comply with our request for
>   submission of the following documents: Original passport or travel
>   document You are welcome to reapply if you feel that you can respond
>   to these concerns and can demonstrate that your situation meets the
>   requirements. All new applications must be accompanied by a new
>   processing fee.

Here's subsection 16(1) of the IRPA https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/i-2.5/section-16.html

Comment: ‘Refused’ or ‘returned’? Without your passport the application may be considered incomplete and therefore not processed. What was the exact text of the notification?

Comment: The status says 'refused'. I edited the question to include what the letter reads

Comment: If they say "refused," then you must answer "yes" to a question in a future visa application about having been previously refused. You should attempt to explain that you had a medical emergency and were not able to submit your passport; include confirming documentation. Whether this will affect another visa application is impossible to say, as no one can assess the other strengths or weaknesses of a future visa application, nor how much weight (if any) Canada will give to this refusal.

Comment: @David shame. I am sending them an email to provide evidence to my medical emergency hoping that they will change the status to cancelled or withdrawn. I don't put too much hope but at least I tried.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this will affect you negatively, because from Canada's perspective it is a refusal. It's a very unfortunate refusal, because most likely you had been approved for the visa and Canada was going to stamp it in your passport.

(If it was possible to do, you should have submitted your passport for visa stamping, even though you could not go on that specific trip. Then you would have had a valid Canada visa you could use later for future journeys.)

You will have to disclose the visa refusal whenever a country asks specifically about visa refusals of other countries. But if the country does not ask, you do not need to disclose it.

The best way to clear this up is to reapply for the visa and be approved. Then, if anyone asks about the refusal, you can simply say you reapplied and got the visa.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That’s a shame, I am not sure if they can undo the status but i am contacting them now and providing my medical emergency letter. Hopefully they will accept and change the status to withdrawn or anything.